# Getting invalid input records for HTTP POST request using cURL in PHP Microsoft Cognitive Services

Tags: php, curl, post

This has been driving me nuts. Using Microsoft's Cognitive Services, I'm trying to post some text to the sentiment analysis RESTful service using PHP and cURL. I feel like I've followed the instructions to a T here https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c9

But I cannot for the life of me get my code to work.

```
$body = array(
    "documents" => array(
    "language" => "en",
    "id" => "one",
    "text" => "Well, look, you look back at George W. Bush’s administration, he selected people who were very close to his family, to his father, and so you do see some of that. But it’s interesting.",
     ),
   );

$API_Endpoint ="https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/text/analytics/v2.0/sentiment";
$headers = ['Content-Type: application/json','Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:{myactualkeyhere}',];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($body));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TRANSFERTEXT, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo json_encode($result);
```

The error that I get back is

```
"{\"code\":\"BadRequest\",\"message\":\"Invalid request\",\"innerError\":{\"code\":\"InvalidRequestContent\",\"message\":\"Missing input records.\"}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to answer my own question after much thought and trial and error. Originally I thought the issue was with my headers, I kept getting errors back about needing an API key, even though it was clearly in the header. But the issue turned out to be a very rudimentary PHP array creation issue that I just missed because I'm a noob.

The correct array syntax is:

```
                   $body = array (
                                  'documents' => 
                                  array (
                                    0 => 
                                    array (
                                      'language' => 'en',
                                      'id' => 'one',
                                      'text' => $text,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                );
```

I'm hoping this helps other noobs like me trying to curl RESTful API endpoints in PHP. Good luck!